# How to exclude certain value of an array with lodash or any other better method

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to display a particular value of an Object in an array for eg This is my array:

```
{  
    _id: "myid",  
    typeFilter: "two",  
    brand: "ABC",  
    mrp: "50,000.00",  
    Insurance: "1,596.00",  
    registration_charg: "5,510.16"  
},
// ...
{
    _id: "myid2",  
    typeFilter: "three",  
    brand: "ABC",  
    mrp: "40,000.00",  
    Insurance: "8,596.00",  
    registration_charg: "7,580.16"  
},
// ...
```

This is what I fetch from my database so here the `brand` value is  ABC in 2 places
In my code I am displaying only the brand values in a Picker So what I get is 2 times the same brand, I want to make it appear only once
So how can I achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using lodash:

```
var brands = _.uniq(_.map(array, "brand"));
```

`_.map` will get an array of all brand names (including duplicates), then `_.uniq` will remove the duplicates and return an array of unique values.

Answer (score 2):

If ES6 is not a problem, You can use Set to get a list of brand without duplicates:

```js
var arr= [
{  
    _id: "myid",  
    typeFilter: "two",  
    brand: "ABC",  
    mrp: "50,000.00",  
    Insurance: "1,596.00",  
    registration_charg: "5,510.16"  
},
{
    _id: "myid2",  
    typeFilter: "three",  
    brand: "ABC",  
    mrp: "40,000.00",  
    Insurance: "8,596.00",  
    registration_charg: "7,580.16"  
}
];

var brands = Array.from(new Set(arr.map(el => el.brand)));
console.log(brands);
```

Comment: can u pls explain this `var brands = Array.from(new Set `

Comment: Array.from just converts the set to array and the new Set returns a set of unique values

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDuplicates(myArr, prop) {
  return myArr.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
    return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
  });
}
```

`myArr` is an array of objects. this function return an array that do not contain the duplicate prop values.In your case, you can pass the array and the brand

Comment: This is worked for me. it will return unique objects